# vuejs mounted createElement dynamic value problem

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Hi i am trying to add dynamic value from json file to my script tag in vuejs component
but i cannot get it to work. i dont't know what am i doing wrong?

```
import privateToursData from '@/data/privateToursData.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      privateTour: privateToursData,
 }
}
 mounted () {
    const plugin = document.createElement("script");
    plugin.setAttribute(
        "src",
        `${this.privateTour.bokunStandardScript}`
    );
    plugin.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(plugin);

  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the json ? you are importing from json, either you need fetch or make that a constant variable to export as data not json.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your data, and source using in the script tag. It correct and working for a hard coded source / link.

Either you need to make it a js object or `fetch()` a json as XHR request to load in runtime. Better go with js object if your value will be hard coded.

```
import  {jsonData}  from "./data.js"
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
    mounted : function () {
    const plugin = document.createElement("script");
    plugin.setAttribute(
        "src",
        jsonData.link
    );
    plugin.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(plugin);
  }
  
}
```

**data.js**

```
export const jsonData =  {
  "link": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
}
```

Here is complete implementation : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ty7jbp?file=src/components/data.js)